# redirect Django to custom page after social login and then redirecting to previous page using ?next

Tags: django, django-3.0

In django,

When user logs in using **Login from google**, I am redirecting it to `/user/profile/picture/` where I am doing some code to store profile picture in another table.

Then I want to redirect the user to previous page where he/she clicked *Siginin in with google*

---

**What I have tried:**

**In settings.py**

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/user/profile/picture/'`

**In home.html**

`<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}?next={{request.path}}">`

The main problem is here. Django redirects to `/user/profile/picture/` and it loses the `next` parameter. And if I remove the line `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/user/profile/picture/`, the problem is that it will not create a new row in table for setting profile picture and it will directly redirect to previous page using `next` paramter.

---

**What I want?**

I want django to redirect me first to `user/profile/picture` and then redirect me to the previous page where user clicked on *Sigin with Google*

**PS:** I am using django 3.0.5 if it makes any difference.